# Is this grammar in VB.Net allowed? (Procedure as argument)

Tags: vb.net, lambda, grammar, arguments

```
Public Class ABC
    Public Sub Foo()
        AA.Bar(nothing, Sub()
                        End Sub)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Hello guys, 
I feel confused at the second argument of function AA.Bar, this argument is specified as a Sub/End Sub procedure.

1. What is the function AA.Bar's possible definition looks like?
   An event? Delegate? Pointer like?...
2. Where can I find the latest VB.NET Grammar Specification?
3. What are the new features in VB.NET 4?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would guess an `Action`. Obviously ["it's allowed"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx), so consider *writing a better title* and focusing on one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub Bar(string str, Action method)

End Sub
```